# redirect http urls to https with 301 in .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect `http://www.example.com/page/` urls to  `https://www.example.com/page/` and have tried some code suggestions from here but was getting infinite redirect loops. I also tried using cpanel but that gave 404 errors. I have also moved the redirects above the mod_rewrite section when doing it from cpanel as they normally don't work otherwise.

Am using current wordpress + cloudflare with HTTPS plugin to keep whole site in `https://www` which is working well.

This is what I can find in wp-config.php and .htaccess currently:

wp-config.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Preferably, any attempts to access a `http://www.example.com/page/` url would result in a 301 redirect to the `https://www.example.com/page/` 
version of the same url.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/116206

Comment: Thanks Unamata, The mod rewrite rule worked from your link. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a plugin instead?

I suspect this plugin may do exactly what you want:

WordPress HTTPS (SSL) https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/

If that doesn't solve the problem you could try something like this using mod_alias

```
Redirect permanent /page https://www.example/com/page
```

in your the site file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Comment: Hi Jason, yes that is the plugin I am using, which keeps my site on https. But there are a whole bunch of cached http:// urls in google that show each day and when i enter one of the urls in the browser it stays as http://, hence it would be good to have a 301 to make it https so google gets the picture eventually and so people don't bookmark the http urls

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind Jason, I wasn't sure whether code could be written like that, but good to see it can. Mod rewrite rule is working now from the server fault link above.